# mongo geoNear with lookup aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I have collection places which have field location. I also have a collection seats which have placeId field.

What I am trying to do is select the seats with places (as a foreign key) and do geoLocation with argument called location (which contains lat and long) on a places.location field.

by now I have this

`fill_database.js`:

```
conn = new Mongo();

db = conn.getDB('test');

db.places.remove({});
db.seats.remove({});

db.places.insert({
    placeName: '84th NYC',
    placeAddress: '083 01 Sabinov 9. maja',
    location: {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [49.097968, 21.105365],
    },
});

lastPlace = db.places.find()[0];
db.seats.insert({
    seatName: 'Seat 1',
    description: 'Located in the corner of the room very quiet and comfortable',
    type: 'solo',
    pictures: ['http://lorempixel.com/400/200/'],
    placeId: lastPlace._id,
});
db.seats.insert({
    seatName: 'Seat 21',
    description: 'Located by the window, bright setting, very quiet and comfortable',
    type: 'solo',
    pictures: ['http://lorempixel.com/400/200/'],
    placeId: lastPlace._id,
});


db.places.createIndex({location: '2dsphere'});
```

use as `$ mongo fill_database.js`
and this using Mongoose:

`seats.js`:

```
self.aggregate([
    {$geoNear: {near: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [location.lat, location.long]}, distanceField: 'places.dist', maxDistance: 100, includeLocs: 'places.location', spherical: true}},
    {$lookup: {from: 'places', localField: 'placeId', foreignField: '_id', as: 'place'}},
]
```